# MPI_Win_free causes invalid window error

Tags: c++, mpi

Why the MWE causes the following error message?

> Signal: Segmentation fault (11)
>
> Signal code: Address not mapped (1)
>
> ...
>
> MPI_ERR_WIN: invalid window

```
#include <mpi.h>

struct A
{
    MPI_Win win;

    ~A()
    {
        if (win != MPI_WIN_NULL)
        {
            MPI_Win_free(&win);
        }
    }
};

int main()
{
    MPI_Init(NULL, NULL);

    A a;
    a.~A();

    MPI_Finalize();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This code has 2 issues. First, you're not initialising `win` and so when it gets destructed it could be any value - and calling `MPI_Win_free(...)` on a garbage value is bad. Secondly you're manually calling the destructor of `a`. This is *almost* never the right thing to do as then it'll be destructed twice. If you need `a` destructed before you call `MPI_Finalize()` then just scope it:

```
#include <mpi.h>

struct A
{
    MPI_Win win = MPI_WIN_NULL;

    ~A()
    {
        if (win != MPI_WIN_NULL)
        {
            MPI_Win_free(&win);
        }
    }
};

int main()
{
    MPI_Init(NULL, NULL);

    {
        A a;
    }

    MPI_Finalize();

    return 0;
}
```

And lastly, although this code doesn't have an explicit problem as written, obeying the rule of [0/3/5](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three) is always worthwhile.